# jQuery - Parse DOM and create a tree structure (composite pattern)

Tags: javascript, jquery, composite

I am parsing the DOM, and I want to ***extract the hierarchy*** of all elements  that match a certain selector, lets say `$('[data-node]')`, into a JavaScript object tree structure.  I have failed to find a standard jQuery way of doing this.  Using jQuery.find() seems to return a flat list.  Perhaps I have just missed something obvious?

For example, I would like to parse this:

```
<div data-node="root">
   <div class="insignificant-presentation">
        <div>
            <div data-node="interestingItem">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div data-node="anotherInterestingItem">
        <div data-node="usefulItem">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And create a structure in JavaScript like this:

```
[
  {
    "node": "root",
    "children": [
      {
        "node": "interestingItem",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "node": "anotherInterestingItem",
        "children": [
          {
            "node": "usefulItem",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you'd need this, but something like this should do it

```
$.fn.tree = function() {
    var arr  = [],
        self = this;

    (function runForrestRun(el, arr) {
        var isEl = self.is(el),
            children = [];

        if (isEl)
            arr.push({
                "node" : el.data('node'), 
                "children": children
            });

        el.children().each(function() {
            runForrestRun($(this), isEl ? children : arr);
        });

    }(this.first(), arr));

    return arr;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a33vpf3w/)

Comment: I understand the puzzlement over why I might need to do this.  I have a very complicated project, and I have no control of the markup I'm parsing.  Your answer works perfectly though, very impressive.

Comment: This answer has been continuously useful to me (not just in jQuery), is there a common name for this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function createTree(root) {
  var children = [];

  root.find('div[data-node]').each(function() {
    // I can't think of a better way to not match the same ellement twice. 
    if (!$(this).data('tagged')) {
      $(this).data('tagged', true);
      children.push(createTree($(this)));
    }
  });

  return {
    "node": root.data('node'),
    "children": children
  };
}

var tree = createTree($('div[data-node]').first());

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([tree], 0, 2))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-node="root">
  <div class="insignificant-presentation">
    <div>
      <div data-node="interestingItem">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div data-node="anotherInterestingItem">
        <div data-node="usefulItem">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, nearly the same as the guy who answered a little bit earlier than you and solved the problem, but I think I prefer his use of $.fn and self.is.

Comment: @IanL, I agree that adeneo solution is the better choice. They are quite similar as there is only so many ways to write the function recursively.